# Is Laravel Sail deployment-ready

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile, laravel-sail

I've recently started using `Laravel Sail` and I've noticed that it uses the built-in PHP server and not something like `Apache` or `Nginx`. So, I assume that this way is not a good way to deploy it on `Laravel Vapor`.

I can publish the `Dockerfiles` of `Sail` and modify them to include Nginx but I noticed that Sail uses some internal code to launch the server which would be impossible to modify. So, is the only way to have a production-ready Docker environment not using `Laravel Sail`?

I've read all the `Sail` documentation but there is nothing on the topic.

Comment: Laravel sail CLI seems to provide helpers for accessing containers and setting up a local environment. The docker compose file can be used to deploy into production

Comment: I think your question lacks an important part: where do you want to deploy and what infrastructure is available? Docker is a product; what you are asking for is containerization. But the issue with that is, there are many different ways to deploy containers in production (Docker Compose, Kubernetes, cloud offerings, ...).

Comment: I think we can run the app only with docker(sail), but using a database in docker is not a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/123) where someone was asking about getting PHP-FPM as an alternative:

> Sail is meant as a development tool and not as a production tool.

Answer (score 0):

I have this Docker config changes [here on Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/kokyawsithu/laravel-sail-apache). You can check and modify as you need. Please note my configs are meant only for development purpose.